# How do i get the closest next date in an array of dates using moment js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, date, momentjs

Ok i need to get the closest date (hours/minutes) in this array of dates, no matter how far the date is from the current day, say like right now is 13:55PM and this array has

```
[
  11:41,
  14:20,
  15:30,
  22:05,
  23:16,
]
```

so the closest one here is the 14:20, if the current time is 15:31, the next closest date from this new current time is the 22:05, no matter how far the date is (today), the next closest date is the next one, problem is, whenever i run this code, it keeps telling me the next one is 15:30, if the current time is 7:20 as an example, the next closest date is guess what, 15:30 :(

this is the code i'm running

```
  getFechaSiguiente() {
    // Current time in millis
    const now = +Moment(Moment().format('HH:mm'), 'HH:mm').format('x');
    // Times in milliseconds
    const timesInMillis = DataManager.ListaFechaCita.map(t => +Moment(t, 'HH:mm').format('x')); //times.map(t => +moment(t, "HH:mm").format("x"));

    function closestTime(arr: any, time: any) {
      return arr.reduce(function(prev: any, curr: any) {
        return Math.abs(curr - time) < Math.abs(prev - time) ? curr : prev;
      });
    }
  
    const closest = Moment(closestTime(timesInMillis, now)).format('HH:mm');
    return closest;
  }
```

let's pretend DataManager.ListaFechaCita is the array of dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the delta of your time with the `time` value from `times` array and then return the value which is positive.

```js
const times = [ '11: 41', '14: 20', '15: 30', '22: 05', '23: 16'];
const compareTime = moment('15:31', 'hh:mm');
const closestTime = times.find((time) => {
  const diff = moment(time, 'hh:mm').diff(compareTime, 'minutes');
  return diff >= 0;
});
console.log(closestTime);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: i tested your code on jsfiddle, but when i change your 13:55 to 15:55, the next closest hour shows me 15:30 instead of 22:05

Comment: It is returning the time which has the lowest delta. Do you want next closest time?

Comment: Please check the updated code. I am assuming your `times` array is sorted.

Comment: it works, best solution so far, i'm checking yours as the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the array by the time difference between the given value and pick the first element:

Ex:

```
a = [10,20,30,40,50]
b = 18
c = a.sort((x1,x2)=> Math.abs(x1-b) - Math.abs(x2-b) )[0] //20
```

The same operation works with momentjs objects:

```
a = [moment('10:30','HH:mm'), 
     moment('11:30','HH:mm'), 
     moment('15:30','HH:mm')]
b = moment('12:00','HH:mm')
c = a.sort((x1,x2)=> Math.abs(x1-b) - Math.abs(x2-b) )[0] // 11:30
```

Comment: not bad but the idea is whenever the time has already surpassed the previous one from the array, it has to go for the next closest hour

Comment: In that case it is even simpler: